# Inline pictures (with double-spaced caption)

Tags: html, css, image, inline, captions

I've got a problem with my website. I want to put two pictures inline in my header:
(i mean the logo and the branding picture at the top) http://tdfts.com/projects/akvile_test

I tried to float it, but it didn't worked at all. here is an example of the code, i tried:
http://www.ohne-css.gehts-gar.net/0004.php (sorry it's in german :/)

I also tried to create a caption for the team pics at "team". there was also a code for this at the german site, but it didnt worked aswell :( I hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've read and re-read the question but I couldn't understand how it should be. Could you expand on `it didn't worked at all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use table, that will give best result...

```
<table><tr>  <td><img /></td>  <td style="padding-left:10px;"><img /></td>  </tr></table>
```

---

After watching your code I found problem: **You need to put `style="display:inline-block;"` in `div id="logo"`**. But remember, there is an restriction that width of both images should be less than page width. If user change the screen resolution, browser width then second image will come on second line. SO, best will be to use TABLE TAG, put logo-div in first TD and brand-image in second TD.

Comment: thanks! i've just updated my website. there's only a little problem with the caption at "team". between the first and the second line of the caption is very much space

Comment: @user3838625 why are you typing those in different row... put second caption with first one. `<tr>    <td><p>Co-founder Vilgaile</p><p>India &amp; Lithuania</p></td><td style="padding-left: 12px;"><p>Co-founder Akvile</p><p>Germany &amp; Lithuania</p></td>  </tr>`   || By the way problem is: Margin in <P> tag, but not able to find which CSS is doing that. Debugging only shows that margin-left:20px from style.css line 118; but there is 16px-top-and-bottom space is also, that's why gap is there. But not able to track, so use my above alternative to put in same ROW.

Answer (score 0):

I put a float:left on the , and it worked very nicely.

Remember:  float only works on sibling elements, not on children-of-sibling, and float only works when specified on the earlier sibling(s), not the later siblings.